Debugging Semaphore issues and GDB Access issue
After compiling my test files test00.c-test13.c I recieve the same output for each from running ./test00
student@EC2AMAZ-PCA3LKV:/mnt/d/Dev/usloss-dev/phase4$ ./test00
p1_fork called for process 1
p1_fork called for process 2
Switching from process 0 to process 2
p1_fork called for process 3
Switching from process 0 to process 3
p1_fork called for process 4
Switching from process 0 to process 4
start3(): Initializing system components...
p1_fork called for process 5
Switching from process 0 to process 5
Switching from process 0 to process 4
p1_fork called for process 6
Switching from process 0 to process 6
Error waiting on semaphore 0, result -1

I recieve Error waiting on semaphore 0, result -1. The point of the program is  testing fundamental operations like process creation, context switching, and semaphore operations within a simulated OS environment. The test aims to verify that the process management and synchronization mechanisms are functioning correctly in your implementation.
Here is semaphores.c
#include "sems.h"
#include "usloss.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "provided_prototypes.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "phase4.h"
#include "driver.h"

typedef struct {
    int procId;
    int wakeTime; // Time at which the process should be woken up
} TimedWait;

typedef struct {
    int value;
    int mutex;
    List waitingProcs; // Existing list for processes waiting normally
    List timedWaitingProcs; // New list for processes waiting until a specific time
} Semaphore;



Semaphore semTable[MAXSEMS];

void block_on_condition(int semId, int wakeTime) {
    Semaphore* sem = &semTable[semId];
    obtainMutex(sem->mutex);

    if (sem->value > 0) {
        sem->value--;
    }
    else {
        // Create a timed wait structure
        TimedWait tw = { getCurrentProcessID(), wakeTime };
        addToList(&sem->timedWaitingProcs, &tw);
        releaseMutex(sem->mutex);
        // Block process - receive on its mailbox
        MboxReceive(getProcessMailbox(getCurrentProcessID()), NULL, 0);
        obtainMutex(sem->mutex);
    }

    releaseMutex(sem->mutex);
}

void check_and_wake_timed_waits() {
    int currentTime;
    gettimeofday_real(&currentTime);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSEMS; i++) {
        Semaphore* sem = &semTable[i];
        obtainMutex(sem->mutex);

        Node* node = sem->timedWaitingProcs.head;
        while (node != NULL) {
            TimedWait* tw = (TimedWait*)node->data;
            if (currentTime >= tw->wakeTime) {
                // Wake the process
                MboxSend(getProcessMailbox(tw->procId), NULL, 0);
                Node* toRemove = node;
                node = node->next;
                removeFromList(&sem->timedWaitingProcs, toRemove);
            }
            else {
                node = node->next;
            }
        }

        releaseMutex(sem->mutex);
    }
}

int semp_real(int semId) {
    // Validate semaphore ID before attempting to access it
    if (semId < 0 || semId >= MAXSEMS || semTable[semId].value == UNUSED) {
        printf("Error: Invalid or uninitialized semaphore ID %d\n", semId);
        return -1;
    }

    Semaphore* sem = &semTable[semId];  // Point to the correct semaphore
    obtainMutex(sem->mutex);  // Acquire the mutex to protect semaphore data

    printf("Process %d attempting to decrement semaphore %d with current value %d\n", getCurrentProcessID(), semId, sem->value);

    if (sem->value > 0) {
        sem->value--;  // Decrement the semaphore if it has a positive value
        printf("Semaphore %d decremented by process %d, new value: %d\n", semId, getCurrentProcessID(), sem->value);
        releaseMutex(sem->mutex);  // Release mutex after operation
    }
    else {
        printf("Process %d blocked due to insufficient semaphore value at semaphore %d\n", getCurrentProcessID(), semId);
        addToList(&sem->waitingProcs, getCurrentProcessID());  // Add process to waiting list
        releaseMutex(sem->mutex);  // Release mutex before blocking to avoid deadlock
        MboxReceive(getProcessMailbox(getCurrentProcessID()), NULL, 0);  // Block the process
        obtainMutex(sem->mutex);  // Re-acquire the mutex when the process is woken up
        printf("Process %d unblocked and continues after semaphore %d\n", getCurrentProcessID(), semId);
    }

    releaseMutex(sem->mutex);  // Ensure the mutex is always released
    return 0;  // Indicate successful operation
}




int semcreate_real(int value, int* semaphore) {
    if (value < 0) {
        printf("Error: Attempt to create semaphore with negative value %d\n", value);
        return -1;
    }

    Semaphore sem;
    sem.value = value;
    sem.mutex = MboxCreate(1, 0);
    initList(&sem.waitingProcs);       // Assuming you have a function to initialize lists
    initList(&sem.timedWaitingProcs);  // Initialize the list for timed waits

    int semId;
    for (semId = 0; semId < MAXSEMS; semId++) {
        if (semTable[semId].value == UNUSED) {
            semTable[semId] = sem;
            *semaphore = semId;
            printf("Created semaphore %d with initial value %d\n", semId, value);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Error: No available slots to create new semaphore\n");
    return -1;
}





int semv_real(int semId) {
    if (semId < 0 || semId >= MAXSEMS || semTable[semId].value == UNUSED) {
        printf("Error: Invalid semaphore ID %d\n", semId);
        return -1;
    }

    obtainMutex(semTable[semId].mutex);
    printf("Process %d attempting to increment semaphore %d\n", getCurrentProcessID(), semId);

    if (!isListEmpty(&semTable[semId].waitingProcs)) {
        int procID = removeFromList(&semTable[semId].waitingProcs);
        printf("Semaphore %d waking up process %d\n", semId, procID);
        MboxSend(getProcessMailbox(procID), NULL, 0);
    }
    else {
        semTable[semId].value++;
        printf("Semaphore %d incremented by process %d, new value: %d\n", semId, getCurrentProcessID(), semTable[semId].value);
    }

    releaseMutex(semTable[semId].mutex);
    return 0;
}





void obtainMutex(int mutex) {
    int status = MboxReceive(mutex, NULL, 0);
    if (status != 0) {
        console("Failed to obtain mutex\n");
    }
}

void releaseMutex(int mutex) {
    int status = MboxSend(mutex, NULL, 0);
    if (status != 0) {
        console("Failed to release mutex\n");
    }
}


and test00.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <usloss.h>
#include <phase1.h>
#include <phase2.h>
#include "phase3.h"
#include "phase4.h"
#include <usyscall.h>
#include <libuser.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define ABS(a,b) a-b > 0 ? a-b : -(a-b)

int Child(char *arg) 
{
  int begin, end, time;
  int me = atoi(arg);

  printf("Child%d(): Going to sleep for 10 seconds\n", me);
  GetTimeofDay(&begin);
  Sleep(10);
  GetTimeofDay(&end);
  time = end - begin;
  time = ABS(10000000, time);
  if (time > 1000000) {
    printf("Child%d(): Sleep bad: %d %d\n", me, time, ABS(10000000, time));
  }
  else {
    printf("Child%d(): Sleep done at time %d\n", me, end);
  }
  Terminate(1);

  return 0;
} /* Child */


int start4(char *arg)
{
  int pid, status;
  
  printf("start4(): Start 5 children who all sleep for 10 seconds. Upon\n");
  printf("          waking up, each child checks if its sleep time was at\n");
  printf("          least 10 seconds.\n");

  Spawn("Child1", Child, "1", USLOSS_MIN_STACK, 4, &pid);
  Spawn("Child2", Child, "2", USLOSS_MIN_STACK, 4, &pid);
  Spawn("Child3", Child, "3", USLOSS_MIN_STACK, 4, &pid);
  Spawn("Child4", Child, "4", USLOSS_MIN_STACK, 4, &pid);
  Spawn("Child5", Child, "5", USLOSS_MIN_STACK, 4, &pid);
  Wait(&pid, &status);
  Wait(&pid, &status);
  Wait(&pid, &status);
  Wait(&pid, &status);
  Wait(&pid, &status);
  printf("start4(): Test sleep done.\n");
  Terminate(0);
  
  return 0;
}


I tried using gdb to debug the program by setting breakpoints at semp_real, semv_real, and start3, then running run command, but got the output:
gdb ./test00

Reading symbols from ./test00...
(gdb) break semp_real
Breakpoint 1 at 0xafb0
(gdb) break semv_real
Breakpoint 2 at 0xa9f0
(gdb) break start3
Breakpoint 3 at 0xbd00: file phase4.c, line 215.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /mnt/d/Dev/usloss-dev/phase4/test00
warning: opening /proc/PID/mem file for lwp 54.54 failed: No such file or directory (2)Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 2.
Cannot access memory at address 0x800a9f0
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x800afb0
Cannot insert breakpoint 3.
Cannot access memory at address 0x800bcea

And I keep getting the warning that its trying to open mem file from proc/PID/mem but I dont have a file in that directory.
I tried to use sudo tee to write to the file admin privileges but this didnt help
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
Are there any suggestions on how I can debug my program or figure out my semaphore error?

Not an immediate issue, but your ABS macro is hitting at least two different macro pitfalls (not parenthesized arguments that could lead to precedence issues, multiple evaluations of the same argument). Consider replacing it with a function.

What is your "simulated OS environment" -- it doesn't look like you are running a real OS, and GDB may be getting confused about where in memory the actual ends up running.
